# Listagem de imagens dentro de um diretório

Tags: php, while, galeria

Quero listar as imagens de um diretório, mas não estou conseguindo. Está listando a quantidade certa e tudo mais, mas as imagens não aparecem.

```
<?php
    $path = "http://www.imaginew.com.br/administrar/foto_portifolio/galeria/";
    $diretorio = dir($path);

    echo "Galeria de Imagens '<strong>".$path."</strong>':<br />";

    while($arquivo = $diretorio -> read()){ 
        echo " <img src='".$path."/".$arquivo."' width='80' height='80' class='img-thumbnail'>";
    }

    $diretorio -> close();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Melhor usar directory Iterator.

```php
$path = "/var/www/html/imagens";

foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $fileInfo) {
    if ($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . "<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Deu certo mas listou os nomes.. e pra listar as imagens ?

Comment: assim listou mas não puxa as imagens eu acho que é pelo .htacces.. que tá pedindo link direto .. tipo http://www.meusite.com.br entende? meu código agora tá assim: <?php
                      $diretorio = "administrar/foto_portifolio/galeria/";

foreach (new DirectoryIterator($diretorio) as $fileInfo) {
    if ($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;

     echo " <a class='fancybox' data-fancybox-group='gallery'  href='".$diretorio."/".$fileInfo->getFilename()."' title=''>
                    <img src='".$diretorio."/".$fileInfo->getFilename()."' width='80' height='80'>
                  </a> "; } ?>

Comment: Então, vc ta colocando como src o diretório, neste ponto tu tem que trocar pra tua URL

$path é referente ao caminho físico do arquivo (no servidor)

o src é referente à URL do arquivo (caminho "virtual").

Você pode fazer é $url_base = "http://seudominio.com.br" . $path;

E na imagem usar ``<img src="{$url_base}{$fileInfo->getFilename()}" />``

Comment: <?php

                      $url_base = "http://imaginew.com.br";
                      $diretorio = "administrar/foto_portifolio/galeria/";

                      foreach (new DirectoryIterator($diretorio) as $fileInfo) {
                      if ($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;

                    echo "<img src='.{$url_base}{$fileInfo->getFilename()}.' height='80' >";
                     }  /*
?>

Comment: coloquei assim mas não está listando as imagens está pegando só a principal .. que eu chamo mais acima..

Comment: + 1 Acho que a solução é esta mesmo, basta referenciar os caminhos corretamente. Fiz alguns testes aqui e estou postando abaixo uma resposta com o resultado que consegui (seguindo a dica desta resposta).

Comment: Faltou o http ou o https no começo.  ($url_base = "http://www.bbbbb") (O stack overflow está removendo o http do começo do url base, monte a URL completa http: // www)

De toda forma, está listando apenas 1? Quantas imagens existem na pasta?

Answer (score 2):

Conforme disse o @Willian em sua resposta, você pode utilizar a função `DirectoryIterator` para visualizar o conteúdo de diretórios e arquivos com PHP.

Esta função vai retornar um objeto com vários dados, que podem ser recolhidos através de índices. Os principais que você irá utilizar são:

- `isDir`: verifica se é um diretório (mudei de `isDot`da resposta do Willian, porque achei que fazia mais sentido)
- `getFilename`: Retorna o nome do arquivo do elemento atual do diretório

Veja uma relação completa [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.directoryiterator.php).

Continuando, antes de tudo você precisa utilizar uma saída para receber os erros do script, então use `error_reporting` e `ini_set` logo no início do script, após `<?php`:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Assim, você receberá a descrição dos erros, e ficará mais fácil de debugar. O erro será algo assim:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with
>   message
>   'DirectoryIterator::__construct(/var/www/html/galeria/):
>   failed to open dir: No such file or directory' in
>   /var/www/html/galeria.php on line 7

No caso, tentando implementar aqui a solução postada pelo @Willian, percebi que o problema era justamente indicar os caminhos, e isso passa por entender a diferença entre a requisição `http` feita dentro do `foreach` e a indicação do caminho para o `DirectoryIterator`, feita através da variável `$path`.

Então, se `$path` for:

```
$path = "http://www.imaginew.com.br/administrar/foto_portifolio/galeria/";
```

Receberá o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with
>   message
>   'DirectoryIterator::__construct(http://www.imaginew.com.br/administrar/foto_portifolio/galeria/):
>   failed to open dir: not implemented' in galeria.php on line 8

E isto ocorre porque o `DirectoryIterator` busca pelo caminho físico do arquivo (que no linux é `/var/www/...`), enquanto o `src` busca pela URL (caminho virtual).

De forma inversa, se você colocar em `$path` o caminho `/var/www/html/etc...` o `DirectorIterator` irá encontrar corretamente, mas você não poderá usar `$path` no caminho da imagem, pois indicando o caminho assim por exemplo:

```
echo " <img src='".$path."/".$fileInfo->getFilename()."' width='80' height='80' class='img-thumbnail'>";
```

Irá sempre ficar algo como `http://www.imaginew.com.br/var/www/html/administrar/foto_portifolio/galeria/` (o que está errado, na requisição `http` precisaria ser `http://www.imaginew.com.br/administrar/foto_portifolio/galeria/` - sem o `**/var/www/html**`... mas isso vai ficar claro se você incluir as saídas de erro conforme sugeri acima). Isso porque, **se você não indicar o caminho completo** a requisição `http` feita pelo `src` já parte do caminho do diretório em que você está, e pega o valor da variável como restante do caminho.

A solução é criar outra variável pra ser usada na hora de buscar a imagem:

```
$path = "/var/www/html/administrar/foto_portifolio/galeria/"; // esta é pra usar no `DirectorIterator`

$dirPath = "http://www.imaginew.com.br/administrar/foto_portifolio/galeria/"; // e esta é pra usar dentro do `foreach` ao chamar a imagem
```

Ou apenas indicar o caminho completo no momento de chamar a imagem:

```
echo " <img src='http://www.imaginew.com.br/administrar/foto_portifolio/galeria/{$fileInfo->getFilename()}' />";
```

Então o código normalizado fica assim:

```
$path = "/var/www/site/html/administrar/foto_portifolio/galeria/";
$dirPath = "http://www.imaginew.com.br/administrar/foto_portifolio/galeria/";

foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $fileInfo) {
    if ($fileInfo->isDir()) continue;
    echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . "<br />\n";
    echo " <img src='$dirPath{$fileInfo->getFilename()}' />";

}
```

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta, upvote